# How to track whether entity has been modified from the UI using ASP.NETCore and in EF Core after posting the request from browser (client)?

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Scenario: fetching an entity object from DBContext (EF Core and LINQ) and navigating to a page (MVC) to display the data and there is a save button enabled (by default) on screen. when user clicks on save button then I want to know whether entity state to see whether its  modified or not. I am getting always entity state its detached. I think it is due to disconnected from the current DBcontext , in my case I am updating timestamp field "Modifed" but I want to stop save changes to db if entity is unchanged, is it possible to track entity state in this scenario?

Comment: Is it an option to read the current entity from the context before updating it with any new data you have?

Comment: You can't dude, the DbContext entity tracker in the page load time, differs from the tracker after the second request and is being constructed by Dotnet Dependency Resolver.

Comment: All you can do is add change tracking to the client code and decide there whether or not to send a save request.

Comment: Also, for simple CRUD, [Breeze](https://breeze.github.io/doc-js/lap-changetracking.html) is a viable option.

Answer (score 1):

In a disconnected environment like web applications, after posting entity from client to server there is no way to find out whether entity is modified or not without fetching the actual entity from the database. You can cache the entity or hash of entity before sending it to client and after receiving the entity from client, compare it with the cached version to avoid unnecessary data fetch.